# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: clang, xcode7, linker-errors, tesseract

I have project with cocoa pods and TesseractOCRiOS - XCODE 7.1 (7B91b)

While I'm building app for iPad (9.1) TesseractOCRiOS Framework failed with this Error

Building on simulator works fine..

I have tried to

- Purge deriver data,
- clean project,
- set ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
- set Build Active Architecture Only=NO

I don't understand what this error means :(

```
    Ld /Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR normal armv7
    cd /Users/whipstercz/git/sw-paperless-app/sw-paperless/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -L/Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/whipstercz/git/sw-paperless-app/sw-paperless/Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/lib -F/Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TesseractOCR.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -weak_library /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib -llept -lstdc++ -ltesseract_all -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TesseractOCR_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/whipstercz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sw-paperless-flbrahykkapkkfeylglxcishyehc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR

ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: So you don't understand the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I have found Error

Problem was that i had more cocoa pods dependecies.
Not all of them had ENABLE_BITCODE flag disabled

Comment: This helped me.  Thank you.